# how to pass argument to executable in launchfile

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Want to start a executable within a launchfile which needs an argument (its note a node),
normally i would launch that executable like this from the commandline:

setuart2 on

where "on" is the argument.

I've  put the executable into a scriptfolder into the workspace and am starting it like that in the launchfile:

, seems that it is found through the launchfile, but i get the following error (what is clear, because the parameter "on" is missing:

killing on exit
remote[robotOS.local-0]: /home/robot/ROS-Groovy-Workspace/src/base_controller/scripts/setuart2: either 'on' or 'off' argument is required

Now i've found no way to pass the parameter, tryed it throug parameters, but no success.

Can somebody help?

Thx a lot
Fabian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213429/how-to-pass-argument-to-executable-in-launchfile/) by [fabian77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20410/fabian77/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2015-07-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try using the `args` property:

```
<node name="setuart2" pkg="base_controller" type="setuart2" args="on"/>
```

But also note that roslaunch assumes that any nodes listed are ROS nodes, and silently passes additional `__name` and `__log` parameters to your program (which ROS nodes handle correctly).

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fabian77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20410/fabian77/) on 2015-07-10**:
Hi, thanks for having a look, allready tried with args, but no success. Still getting error:

/home/robot/ROS-Groovy-Workspace/src/base_controller/scripts/setuart2: either 'on' or 'off' argument is required

**Comment by [fabian77](https://answers.ros.org/users/20410/fabian77/) on 2015-07-10**:
maybe i just try writing a scriptfile which passes the argument correct and trying to execute that script instead...

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-07-10**:
Your program is probably confused by the `__name` and `__log` options I mentioned. Try writing a ROS node which calls your program.